# Position text in div layer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How I can put this button on the right side of the div?

```
<div>
  <h1>Sensors</h1>

  <h:form id="new_sensor_button">
    <p:commandButton value="New Sensor" id="ajax" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />
  </h:form>
</div>
```

Expected output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on a couple of comments and a question edit.

The simplest method today is to use Flexbox to accomplish that, see notes in CSS

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;        /* align them side-by-side (is default so can be omitted ) */
  align-items: center;        /* vert. align items */
  max-width: 100%;
}

form#new_sensor_button {
  margin-left: auto;          /* right align form/button */
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sensors</h1>

  <form id="new_sensor_button">
    <button value="New Sensor" id="ajax" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

If it is not possible to target the form, do like this

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

button#ajax {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Sensors</h1>

  <form id="new_sensor_button">
    <button value="New Sensor" id="ajax" styleClass="ui-priority-primary"></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, How the button text can be vertically aligned?

Comment: @PeterPenzov That is actually a new question, though I will update my answers showing that.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Added a 2nd sample

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Yes, there is many...too many for me to show them all. To suggest a proper solution we need to see an expected output, i.e. with a drawing or similar, or else this can take forever until I eventually show the one that is correct for you.

Comment: I updated the post with expected result and original code. Can you give some advice how I can make the proper visual result?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Updated

Comment: Thanks. How I can set these properties to component with unique id not to button: form {
  margin-left: auto;                 /* right align form/button */
}

Comment: @PeterPenzov Don't understand what you mean by that. If you take the time to try understand what I did, you should be able to adjust yourself

Comment: How I can edit this part of the css code: form {
  margin-left: auto;         
} to  .button_id {
  margin-left: auto;         
}  and get the same visual result? I have several buttons. I need to apply this style only to one button.

Comment: @PeterPenzov You need to deal with the form that holds the button, or remove the form, still, can't see how that matters. Made an update to show a second sample

Comment: Ok, but how I an apply the css code to a specific components with unique ID? I have several forms and buttons.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Since the form holds the button you need to target the form, but as the form has an unique id, use that `form#new_sensor_button`. Updated my answer

Comment: @PeterPenzov I added one more solution for you, just in case :)